# How can I add two security policies in Spring MVC App?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm writing spring application to serve mobile as well as web portal requests.
I have added Controller to handle web portal requests and RestController to handle mobile requests. This all stuff I have done in single project.

I've configured auth.xml for authetication and all.

```
    <security:http  pattern="/api/**" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless" >                       
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/auth" access="permitAll" /> 
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/token" access="permitAll"  />
            <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"   />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />


            <security:logout />
        </security:http>

        <bean class="com.auth.TokenAuthenticationFilter"
            id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"><value>/api/**</value></constructor-arg>
        </bean>


<!--  Code for REST API Authentication  -->

    <!-- create-session="stateless" -->

    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="ajaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true">     
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />


        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationFilter" />
        <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />

        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.do" invalidate-session="true" />
        <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeService" />
        <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

    </security:http>
```

But I want  to integrate Spring OAuth 2.0 in it.
Can anyone has idea about the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure 2 different security filters for 2 different paths. That way, you can have differents paths of you application secured differently. Typically, you would want to have "/public/**" accessible to anyone while "/api/**" being secured by authentication.

I would strongly recommend to configure Spring Security in Java by extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**.

Here is an example Java configuration which protects only some endpoints while leaving others accessible publicly.

```js
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", OPTIONS.toString()),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/health"),
    // Spring Social
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/signin/**"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/**"),
    // Swagger Documentation
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui.html"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v2/api-docs"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-resources/**"),
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/webjars/**")
  );
  private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

  @Autowired
  private RESTAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
  @Autowired
  private TokenService credentials;
  @Autowired
  private UserSecurityService users;

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .exceptionHandling()
      // this entry point handles when you request a protected page and you are not yet
      // authenticated
      .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
      .and()
      .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
      .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .authorizeRequests()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .csrf().disable()
      .formLogin().disable()
      .httpBasic().disable()
      .logout().disable()
      .sessionManagement().disable();
  }

  @Bean
  RESTAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final RESTAuthenticationFilter filter =
      new RESTAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS, credentials);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(getSuccessHandler());
    return filter;
  }

  // Upon successful authentication, Spring will attempt to try and move you to another URL
  // We have to prevent this because the request for the resource and the authentication all get done in the same request!
  @Bean
  SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler getSuccessHandler() {
    final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
    return successHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
    return new Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("Bearer");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Octoperf.com

Answer (score -2):

Try out spring security. It has built in functionalities also you can always override existing behavior for your purposes.

Comment: For your information author not tagged question with spring security which  means he is not familiar with spring security

Comment: It does not necessarily mean that, it might as well mean that he doesn't know how to tag questions properly. The supplied config in the question is nevertheless Spring security config.

Comment: And in any case, your answer isn't very helpful, it should have been a comment.